# Serilog printing contextual property

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog and want to print some information message that contains contextual property.

For example:

```
var logger = Log.ForContext("FirstName", "Yosi");
logger.Information("Hello {FirstName}")
```

and this works as expected, but when I add parameter to the log message it self, I get unexpected result.

```
var logger = Log.ForContext("FirstName", "Yosi");
logger.Information("Hello {FirstName} {LastName}", "Attias")
```

I expect the result to be:

> Hello Yosi Attias

but I get:

> Hello Attias {LastName}

Is there a fix for that? am I missing something? or this is a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Message templates are only evaluated against the parameters that are passed in to the logging method. Log statements are intended to work consistently regardless of any other configuration/context in the program.

If you want to add additional properties to the logging output, add them to the `outputTemplate` argument of whatever sink you are configuring:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole(outputTemplate:
    "{Timestamp:HH:mm} [{Level}] ({LastName}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Currently I have logger in my class, and in my method - where I get the context by parameters I add context to the logger.
For example: https://gist.github.com/yosiat/3f98e98ccc586f1ef58a2a23858dd0ee

Can I change the output template for my logger to add the messageId for "messageLogger"?

Comment: Hi Yosi - no, the output template's the only option (aside from custom formatting code) for this at present.

Comment: You can, Yosi. Just try to add to template "{Properties}" - it will output all your context properties to log. For example : "{Timestamp:u} [{Level:w3}] {Message} {NewLine}{Properties}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Exception}"

Answer (score 0):

use refection to add properties and their values automatically to log them all in Serilog:

```
public static Task GenericLog(MyClassLog myclassLog, string message=null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) message = nameof(myclassLog);
    
    var properties = typeof(MyClassLog).GetProperties();

    var propertyEnrichers = new PropertyEnricher[properties.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        propertyEnrichers[i] =
            new PropertyEnricher(
                properties[i].Name,
                properties[i].GetValue(myclassLog)
                );

    var withProps = Log.ForContext(propertyEnrichers);

    withProps.Debug(message);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```